# Cloud vs Virtualization vs SaaS - Preparing My 1st Install

Tags: virtualization, cloud

I'm thinking about taking a stab at Ubuntu-One for cloud and/or virtualization purposes and for my first time although I have distro-hopped Linux desktop for a few years and worked somewhat with Red Hat.

Just curious when you say "Cloud", will I need to set up a physical server and use acting thin client PCs on my home network working as a cloud storage solution or on-demand software? OR is this more of a all-in-one Virtual Box type solution?

When people say things like cloud, virtualization and SaaS/On-demand Software, I always wonder what precisely is their definition?

I know it is somewhat of a noob question and maybe Ubuntu-One can do all of the above. Perhaps directing me to a FAQ area where this is more thoroughly covered?

Comment: Ubuntu One is not a service for setting up and managing virtualized servers.